# vector.size() is working unexpectedly in comparision

Tags: c++, vector, error-handling, segmentation-fault

When I use vector.size() in comparisions it gives unexpected results

```
vector<int> v;
for(int i = 0; i < v.size() -1;++i){
    printf("i = %d\n", i);
    printf("v[i] = %d\n", v[i]);
}
```

since the size of vector is 0, it shoudn't print anything but, it enters for loop and prints `i = 0` and give segmentation fault. But it shouldn't even enter the for loop as `v.size() - 1` is `-1`.

Why is it happening?

Comment: Don't forget that vectors start out *empty*. All and any indexing in an empty vector will be out of bounds and therefore lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Yes but the point is that it shouldn't even enter the loop because vector.size() - 1, is `-1`

Comment: On an unrelated note, why do you use `printf` in C++? Why not `std::cout`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude because when it gives segmentation fault it doesn't display content of cout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is your loop:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < v.size() -1;++i)
```

More specifically, this part of the condition: `v.size() - 1`.

The [`size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) function returns a value of type `size_type`, which if you read e.g. [this `vector` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) will see is an *unsigned* type.

That means when you subtract `1` from the value `0`, you don't get `-1` but instead get a very large value since unsigned underflow wraps around to its highest value.

That means your loop will indeed iterate, at least once, and lead to UB (Undefined Behavior) when you index out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Vector size is an unsigned int, so v.size() - 1 will never be -1 but some very large integer.

Comment: Also, if you use size() - 1 you will miss out the last element when it is not empty...

Comment: I was using it intentionally, so there's no problem there.